# mini.iso on a USB flash drive does not boot!

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I made a USB flash drive with Ubuntu minimal(mini.iso)...it didn't boot in UEFI mode.

Then I used this guide to make it compatible with UEFI: https://www.onetransistor.eu/2015/12/install-ubuntu-minimal-cd-uefi-enabled.html

I still cannot boot the installer...I had Kubuntu on the same flash drive and it booted normally...weird.

what shall I do ?

Comment: Since you have conclusively demonstrated that your machine will boot from a USB stick, the only remaining possibilities seem to be 1) that you somehow mis-made the netinstall (mini.iso) installer, or 2) that your USB hardware is faulty. Do a bit of troubleshooting to rule out #2.

Comment: I changed the USB drive and it worked...